# UI element for FaceID needed for iPhone X login?

Tags: ios, login

Many iOS apps utilize a Touch ID icon button/element on the login screen in order to invoke Touch ID in case the user has dismissed it previously, or never loaded properly within an app.

From a UX standpoint, is an element be needed for iPhone X in case FaceID hasn't been initiated properly? How should users be able to "invoke" Face ID if it's somehow dismissed or disabled while trying to launch an app?

Comment: I feel like iOS 11 would have a CTA or a callback of some sort if such a scenario comes up. Don't think UX has much of a say here.

Comment: My understanding is that Face ID uses the same technical implementation as Touch ID, so if it works the same way, it would just be a UI issue on how to differentiate that difference. Just trying to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/authentication/#face-id-and-touch-id) site, the interface (that I believe you're asking for) for FaceID will look like so:

[image: Face ID Unlock]

Additionally, an icon for FaceID was also seen in the keynote, as shown in two forms below. Similar to TouchID, it will likely be used differently depending on where in the UI it is being invoked from.

**Dark Version**

This version could be used alongside a passcode UI.

[image]

**"Camera" Version**

This version seems to just be used in Apple Pay and in Settings.

[image: FaceID]

[image]

I am highly speculating at this point, as until the phone's release we won't fully know how the UI/UX integration of FaceID works.

Comment: Thank you, Alan. This is how I was envisioning it as well. Do you have a link where you can point me to that documents the official announcements for this? I've seen the Apple Pay version you show, but I hadn't seen the circular "Dark Version" you're showing here. Any citation you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm updating my answer with citations.

Comment: Alan, thanks for citing the Apple Human Interface Guidelines, I had read through that previously, but I still don't see where the "Dark Version" is mentioned.